# splitting string into php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, preg-split

I have an array that outputs the following:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => #EXTM3U 
    [1] => #EXTINF:206,"Weird" Al Yankovic - Dare to be Stupid 
    [2] => E:\Dare to be Stupid.mp3 
    [3] => #EXTINF:156,1910 Fruitgum Company - Chewy, Chewy 
    [4] => E:\Chewy Chewy.mp3 
    [5] => #EXTINF:134,1910 Fruitgum Company - Goody Goody Gumdrops 
    [6] => E:\Goody Goody Gumdrops.mp3 
    [7] => #EXTINF:134,1910 Fruitgum Company - Simon Says 
    [8] => E:\Simon Says.mp3 
    [9] => #EXTINF:255,3 Doors Down - When I'm Gone 
    [10] => E:\When I'm Gone.mp3 [
    11] => #EXTINF:179,? And the Mysterians - 96 Tears**
)
```

I need to split this array then loop through and save each value to the database, e.g:

```
"Weird" Al Yankovic - Dare to be Stupid
 Fruitgum Company - Chewy, Chewy
 Save each value above to database individually.
```

Thanks in advance!

---

*<sup>**Edit**: Added from the comments</sup>*

Let me try and explain in more detail. I start with a string that looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U #EXTINF:266,10cc - Dreadlock Holiday
D:\Music - Sorted\Various Artists\De Beste Pop Klassiekers Disc 1\10cc - Dreadlock Holiday.mp3
#EXTINF:263,1919 - Cry Wolf
D:\Music - Sorted\Various Artists\Gothic Rock, Vol. 3 Disc 2\1919 - Cry Wolf.mp3
#EXTINF:318,3 Doors Down - [Untitled Hidden Track]
D:\Music - Sorted\3 Doors Down\Away From The Sun\3 Doors Down - [Untitled Hidden Track].mp3
```

I'm then trying to strip everything out of this and just have an array of track titles, this is a playlist file for online radio. What I am doing so far:

```
$finaloutput = $_POST['thestring'];
$finaloutput = str_replace('#EXTINF:','',$finaloutput);
$finaloutput = str_replace('#EXTM3U','',$finaloutput);
$finaloutput = preg_split("/\r\n|\r|\n/", $finaloutput);

foreach ($finaloutput as $value) {
  echo $value; echo '<br>';
}
```

But I still have these rows remaining, I need to try and do a `str_replace` between a line break and the end `.mp3`

> D:\Music - Sorted\3 Doors Down\Away From The Sun\3 Doors Down - [Untitled Hidden Track].mp3

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You need to show your code, and explain the specific problem you're encountering.

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I split the initial string into this array using:

$finaloutput = preg_split("/\r\n|\r|\n/", $finaloutput);

But now I have no idea where to begin to remove the bits I don't need and only loop through what I do need, help!

Comment: There is lots of "junk" in the array. I think you need to start by cleaning up what goes in before splitting to an array. cleaning while in an array is harder. or well, I think it is. You have not shown us what it is before it becomes an array. Always try to get good data in before you start doing something with the data. And if that is not possible, clean up as soon as possible

Comment: Ok let me try and explain in more detail, I start with a string that looks like this:

`#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:266,10cc - Dreadlock Holiday
D:\Music - Sorted\Various Artists\De Beste Pop Klassiekers Disc 1\10cc - Dreadlock Holiday.mp3
#EXTINF:263,1919 - Cry Wolf
D:\Music - Sorted\Various Artists\Gothic Rock, Vol. 3 Disc 2\1919 - Cry Wolf.mp3
#EXTINF:318,3 Doors Down - [Untitled Hidden Track]
D:\Music - Sorted\3 Doors Down\Away From The Sun\3 Doors Down - [Untitled Hidden Track].mp3`

Comment: I'm then trying to strip everything out of this and just have an array of track titles, this is a playlist file for online radio.

What I am doing so far:

Comment: '$finaloutput = $_POST['thestring'];
 $finaloutput = str_replace('#EXTINF:','',$finaloutput);
 $finaloutput = str_replace('#EXTM3U','',$finaloutput);
 $finaloutput = preg_split("/\r\n|\r|\n/", $finaloutput);
 
 foreach ($finaloutput as $value) 
 {
  echo $value;
  echo '<br>';
    }'

Comment: But I still have these rows remaining, I need to try and do a str_replace between a line break and the end .mp3

'D:\Music - Sorted\3 Doors Down\Away From The Sun\3 Doors Down - [Untitled Hidden Track].mp3'

Comment: You can try [something like this](https://eval.in/541928) with `preg_match_all`

Comment: I believe you are on the correct path. I'm typing on my phone and can't help you with an answer but it seems you as if you are geting closer. As bobble says, preg_match could work. look at phpliveregex and you can test it quick and easy

Comment: I did not see the link you posted bobble bubble... good job! You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks bobble bubble works a treat!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered. On bobbles answer below there should be a V-shaped button (if I remember correct).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the relevant parts from source by use of [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with a [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/sL4iP5/1).

```
$pattern = '/^#[^,\n]+,\K.*/m';
```

- [`^` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matches start of line in *multiline mode* which is set with `m` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).
- `#[^,\n]+,` matches the part from `#` until `,` by use of a [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).
- [`\K` is used to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match. We don't want the previous part.
- `.*` the part to be extracted: [Any amount](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) until end of the line.

```
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $finaloutput, $out) > 0);
  print_r($out[0]);
```

[PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/542284)

Comment: Wait... isn't 10cc the artist? So [0] and [1] is missing the artist? (It's most likely not my kind of music since I'm not sure, but something in the back of my head says 10cc is a group)

Comment: Well spotted @Andreas, thank you! I did an update and hope it extracts desired parts ( :